# What is an Solarflare Onload stack and how is it related to their Virtual Interface

Tags: kernel, onload, latency, nic, openonload

I am trying to understand what is an openonload stack and what are the benefits of using them. For example why would I split 8 multicast lines into 2 stacks (4 lines each) compared to 1 stack (8 lines for 1 stack). Will it help with RX drops?

I am also confused how this is relevant to their Virtual Interfaces (vNics) - do they get created automatically when we make a new onload stack?

I was trying to get it from their user guide http://www.smallake.kr/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/SF-104474-CD-20_Onload_User_Guide.pdf but they don't really describe it there in full detail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Userspace stack provide advantage. The total gain is based on your application requirement. Onload can tune for your application(spinning mode, interrupt mode etc). Based on my understanding an Onload stack allocates one vNIC per Solarflare network port so it has a dedicated send and receive channel from user mode.

I suggest to refer the latest onload userguide from  https://support.solarflare.com to get clear info.